# IE8 won't return 'true' when radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8

OK, I have a form on a page.  When the page reloads, I need to check the checked status of a radio button.  This works in latest versions of Chrome and Firefox; however, I have to also target IE8.

IE8 doesn't want to return 'true' on this statement:

```
if(document.getElementById("mentor").checked == true) {
// code will go here
}
```

Unfortunately, jquery is not an option.  My question is: Why doesn't IE8 see that element as checked when Chrome and Firefox do?

This my first time to post a question, so go easy on me if I am not explaining correctly or posting incorrectly!

This is the HTML form element I am try to check:

```
<label for="searchType">Search Type: </label>
    <cfinput type="radio" id="mentor" name="searchType" value="mentor" onClick="searchFilter()" checked>Mentor
```

Comment: Could you paste html

Comment: Try triple equal signs.

Comment: what is the result if it's not true - can you alert it / print it into console?

Comment: it's just `if(document.getElementById('mentor').checked)` it returns true if it is. It works with me

Comment: @Hearner - I don't think that will change anything - ofcouse it's more clean.

Comment: @FrankProvost I know but this is what i'm using and it works fine...

Comment: Tom, When are you performing this statement?

Comment: I am performing this statement almost a the end of the page.

Comment: I tried the triple equal signs and no joy.

Comment: But is it triggered by an event, or anything like it?

Comment: i d suggest you try something like this: onClick="searchFilter(this) and in your function you will do something like: function searchFilter(obj) ... obj.checked == true ...

Comment: The event that would trigger this in actually not the onClick, that does something else.  The event that triggers this would be when the page is refreshed.  For example, the user is coming back to this back by click the back button.  It seems that Chrome and Firefox retain the form fields status, including the radio button.  But IE8 SHOWS the radio button as selected, but it doesn't seem to really be 'checked'.

Comment: @FrankProvost The result is 'undefined' and it throws an javascript error.

Comment: Well my last tip would be to wrap the checkbox and react to the wraps click function. All in all you would fake \ create a new \ your own checkbox